# Display multiple spaces in HTML

Tags: html

What is a good way to put **more than one space** in HTML?

To show one space we write `&nbsp;`. For five spaces, we have to write `&nbsp;` five times, and so on.

Is there a better way? Is there a special tag to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like `<span style="margin-left: 20px;"></span>` to create some sort of 20px space between two words. Other than that, no.

Comment: You should not suggest [mixing CSS in with markup](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#separatestyle).

Comment: If you limit yourself to obsolete/dead/buried (and happily so) browsers, there was the `<spacer>` tag on Netscape which could do this.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the

```
<pre>a    text    with        multiple spaces</pre>
```

tag.

Comment: Or, in general, `white-space:pre` on any element via CSS.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if you are not using CSS then `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` is the only way. These days using CSS and adding a spacer `<span>` would be more advisable.

Comment: I agreed with u.I knw in CSS we can do that.Just wana 2 knw in HTML,cn we do that?or any other tag..

Answer (score 0):

It is often best to handle this with CSS instead of HTML. CSS gives you more control over the whitespace than the `<pre>` tag does. Also, browsers apply default styles to `<pre>` that you might not want.

```css
.pre {
  white-space: pre;
}

.pre-wrap {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

body {
  max-width: 12em;
}
```

```html
<div class="pre">Text     that preserves whitespace and does not wrap</div>
<div class="pre-wrap">Text     that preserves whitespace and wraps as needed</div>
<pre>Text     inside a &ltpre&gt; tag also preserves whitespace</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

To actually insert spaces you are stuck with &nbsp; , the other common thing for spacing things out is to use 1x1 pixel gif and set the images with in the IMG tag.

Comment: Please do not suggest [using spacer GIFs](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#dieSpacerGIFsDIE) for presentation.

Comment: I wouldn't recomend it either, but its a technique.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way I have used is to add `<span style="color:white;">(anything  here)</span>`
The bit in the span can be as long or as short as you like- it's not seen. The color of course is the color of the page/section where you place it. I prefer XXXXXXX as X is standard width (unlike M and I) and it's easy to see how many Xs you will need for a given space.

Comment: This isn't good because the white text is still selectable. It also would be read out by screen readers.